# IIS ASP.NET application: How to disable cache from being reset every 24 hours?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET app that runs on IIS.  The first time I visit the webpage, it takes several seconds to initialize.  All subsequent visits to the site is fast.

However, after approximately 24 hours, the cached application resets automatically; causing the ASP.NET app to take several seconds to start again.

How do I disable this IIS feature so that the cache doesn't reset?

The closest thing I could find to this is to [disable the ASP.NET app pool; which the default is 1740 minutes (1 day, 5 hours)](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes).

I tried disabling this feature, however, it doesn't seem to prevent the cache from being reset.

Comment: You should first ask yourself what kind of cache you are using in this web app. In memory data structure? Runtime memory cache? anything else? Without that no meaningful discussion can follow. If that's difficult for you to describe, share some code.

Comment: There's a module called Output Caching can allow you specify some pages for cachine on IIS. https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8kqX.png The link you show is not about cache but app pool recycle. App pool auto recycle to release some resources so that it has better performance at later time.